# Beginner question on conditional probability

Tags: probability

Three soccer players doing penalty kicks.

Player $X$ has a hit ratio of $90$%, Player $Y$ has a hit ratio of $80$%, Player $Z$ has a hit ratio of $70$%.

Player $X$ takes $70$% of penalty kicks, Player $Y$ takes $20$% of penalty kicks, Player $Z$ takes $10$% of penalty kicks.

You hear on the radio that a penalty has just been missed. What's the probablity of $X,Y,Z$ being the one who missed the shot?

---

Do we look for ("$M$ = player missed penalty", "$C$ = player got chosen")

$$P(M|C)=\frac{P(M\cap C)}{P(C)}$$

?

Because if so, i always get wrong values according to the solutions.

Comment: It is the other way round: $P(Z|M)$. I use the random variable $Z$ here, instead of $C$. M:= penalty has just been missed. Z:=Player Z being the one who missed the shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward application of Bayes' Theorem:

$P(X) = .7$, $P(Y) = .2$, and $P(Z) = .1$.

$P(M|X) = .1$, $P(M|Y) = .2$, and $P(M|Z) = .3$.

$$P(X|M) = \frac{P(X) P(M|X)}{P(X) P(M|X) + P(Y) P(M|Y) + P(Z) P(M|Z)}$$

and likewise for $P(Y|M)$ and $P(Z|M)$.  Just plug in the numbers.

Comment: Just found out that our lecture book goofed. It says $P(A|B) = $ ... and then uses $P(A|B)$ in the denominator again instead of $P(B|A)$.

Comment: Well... I assure you that *my* book, ***Pattern classification***, gets this right!